# Creating github action but keep it in private repo only

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have two repos on github for the same code, one is public and one is private. The private is needed when working on sensitive stuff before it is being released.

I just created a github action which will build my software on a push to a specific branch. I think it should only run in the private one. The secrets are set only on the private repo too.

I assume per se there is no real security issue, as the public repo wouldn't have the secrets thus anything pushed there would never run successfully - however, the action would still be triggered, causing the public repo to have always unsuccessful builds, on top of wasting resources to trigger them.

Therefore I think I would only want that action on the private repo. Can I somehow prevent that action to be merged onto the public repo?

The action should be merged to `master` of the private repo, as following branches should branch off there in order to have it run. I usually merge the private `master` into the public `master`, so really it looks hairy, I don't know how to prevent this action "spilling" into the public one?

The only thing I wanted to try is to merge to private-master, then create a .gitignore which will ignore that action - but not sure it will work.

Comment: you are worried that the .github folder is pushed from the private to the public?

Comment: In some ways you could say that. What I am really worried about is that someone changes something in a fork and suddenly a build gets triggered and our environment gets updated. The action uses information from the repo's secrets to push an update to our (dev) machines.

Comment: forked repositories won't push content to your original repo. They have to open a pull request.

Comment: Yeah. I am probably being paranoid

Comment: I'd suggest you to try at first, then report a problem if any. Right now, I don't see why this should not work